# Disabling "Storage space running out" notification in Status Bar?

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, storage, notification-bar

Is there any way to disable the "Storage space running out" notification on Cyanogenmod 10.1.3 [Android 4.2.2], through ADB or otherwise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To permanently disable storage notifications, try long-pressing on the notification, go to `App Info` and uncheck `Show notifications`. You must do it through long-pressing.

If it is un-checkable, hit `Force Stop` and confirm.

This is a known method to get rid of Verizon's persistent Wifi notification: [Similar Guide](http://androidcommunity.com/how-to-remove-the-ongoing-wifi-notification-on-verizon-galaxy-s-4-20130527/)

Hope this helps,

Comment: Forcing stopping Android System got rid of the Storage notification, however the Show notifications checkbox is still not operable.

Comment: Yeah, according to many other posts on here, there's no *permanent* way to disable it. I'm surprised no-one has created an Xposed module for it yet. I'm going to plan on making one when I have free time.

Answer (score 1):

Since the device is rooted you can install a compatible Xposed Framework<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> and then the Xposed module [NotifyClean](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.defim.apk.notifyclean). The [app's description](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.defim.apk.notifyclean) notes:

> You could configure which apps are allowed to create notifications in the top left area, the notification area. If an app creates a notification it will be collected and added to the list.
>
> You could deny all notifications of an app or only specific messages - if it's not a customized notification. So I used it to hide "waiting for connection", but not "you are connected".

Install the module, activate it in Xposed Installer app, reboot the device, wait for the "Storage space running out" notification, long press the notification → App info/details → note the app's label causing that notification. It may possibly be Android System.

Now, launch NotifyClean → tap the entry of the app whose label you noted → select the notification you want to hide (it would turn red). Reboot and the notification would remain hidden.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> <sub>Xposed Framework: [Android 4.x](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer), [Android 5.x and 6.x](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811)</sub>

Comment: I've not tested on that particular notification but I don't suppose the app would fail for that notification.